# Using Django Window Functions on a Filtered QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset

I ran into a surprising conundrum with Window Functions on Filtered QuerySets.

Consider two models: mymodel and relatedmodel where there is a one to many relationship (i.e. relatedmodel has a ForeignKey into mymodel).

I am using something like this:

```
window_lag = Window(expression=Lag("pk"), order_by=order_by)
window_lead = Window(expression=Lead("pk"), order_by=order_by)
window_rownnum = Window(expression=RowNumber(), order_by=order_by)
qs1 = mymodel.objects.filter(relatedmodel__field=XXX)
qs2 = qs1.annotate(row=window_rownnum, prior=window_lag, next=window_lead)
qs3 = qs2.filter(pk=myid)
```

which returns a lovely result for the object pk=myid. I now know its position in the filtered list and its prior and next and I use this to great effect in browsing filtered lists.

Significantly len(qs1) = len(qs2) is the size of the list and len(qs3)=1

Alas I just discovered this breaks badly when the filter is less specific:

```
window_lag = Window(expression=Lag("pk"), order_by=order_by)
window_lead = Window(expression=Lead("pk"), order_by=order_by)
window_rownnum = Window(expression=RowNumber(), order_by=order_by)
qs1 = mymodel.objects.filter(relatedmodel__field__contains=X)
qs2 = qs1.annotate(row=window_rownnum, prior=window_lag, next=window_lead)
qs3 = qs2.filter(pk=myid)
```

In this instance, qs2 suddenly has more rows in it that qs1! And len(qs2)>len(qs1).

Which totally breaks the browser in a sense (as prior and next are not reliable any more). The extra rows are duplicate mymodel objects, wherever more than one relatedmodel object matches the criterion.

I've traced this to the generated SQL.

This is the form of qs1's SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  "mymodel"."id", "mymodel"."order_by" ....
FROM "mymodel"
INNER JOIN "relatedmodel" ON ("mymodel"."id" = "relatedmodel"."mymodel_id")
WHERE ("related_model"."field"::text LIKE '%X%')
ORDER BY "mymodel"."order_by" ASC
```

And this runs fine in my database engine as a SQL query, and returns the same number of rows that Django sees. All good.

Then the SQL that qs2 produces resembles:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "mymodel"."order_by" ASC) AS "row",
  LAG("mymodel"."id", 1) OVER (ORDER BY "mymodel"."order_by" ASC) AS "prior,
  LEAD("mymodel"."id", 1) OVER (ORDER BY "mymodel"."order_by" ASC) AS "next",
  "mymodel"."id", "mymodel"."order_by" ....
FROM "mymodel"
INNER JOIN "relatedmodel" ON ("mymodel"."id" = "relatedmodel"."mymodel_id")
WHERE ("related_model"."field"::text LIKE '%X%')
ORDER BY "mymodel"."order_by" ASC
```

And again this produces the same number of rows as I see in Django but that's more than qs1 when the relatedmodel matches more than once.

I can doctor the SQL and get what I want, namely by windowing after filtering:

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "mymodel"."order_by" ASC) AS "row"
  LAG("mymodel"."id", 1) OVER (ORDER BY "mymodel"."order_by" ASC) AS "prior,
  LEAD("mymodel"."id", 1) OVER (ORDER BY "mymodel"."order_by" ASC) AS "next",
  "id", "order_by" ....
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    "mymodel"."id", "mymodel"."order_by" ....
  FROM "mymodel"
  INNER JOIN "relatedmodel" ON ("mymodel"."id" = "relatedmodel"."mymodel_id")
  WHERE ("related_model"."field"::text LIKE '%X%')
  ORDER BY "mymodel"."order_by" ASC
) AS QS
```

Which works beautifully and returns the same number of rows as qs1 again.

Adding just one window  function inside the SELECT causes the DISTINCT to fail for some reason. DISTINCT works fine without a window function (returning only unique mymodel rows) but adding a window function breaks this.

Using the filter as a subquery on the window function works.

And Django supports subqueries, but I can't find a way to apply them here.

So I wonder if there is a way to do this. Namely, to apply the annotation as a wrapper around the QuerySet rather than as additional columns in the queryset.

Comment: Try thinking of it a little bit differently.  Put the window function in the subquery and the filter clause in the outer query just to see what that does.

Comment: I envisage a problem there. as the  desired result is, to get a filtered QuerySet (a filter an end user applies) and then for that list of objects, to annotate each row with the a row  number (in the list) and PK of prior and next objects on that list to aid in navigating the (filtered) list. If I apply the window functions before filtering then the resulting list has row numbers, priors and nexts from the unfiltered list. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I suppose you're right.  Sorry about my absolute lack of help in the matter.